# tflearn GPU utilization staying low, memory high

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

When I try to use `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):` in my project the GPU is not rly. being used.
The Memory is high(91%) but GPU utilization(1%) is low.
My conclusion is that the gpu is not actually being used.
What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
def main():
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        model = cnn_model.googlenet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3, LR,  output=8,model_name=MODEL_NAME)
        model.fit({'input': batch_x}, {'targets': batch_y}, n_epoch=1,snapshot_step=2500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

cnn_model can be found [here](https://github.com/MrGrimod/gta_self_driving/blob/master/model/cnn_model.py)

While not running: 
[image: while not running]
While running:
[image: while running]

Comment: When Tensorflow instantiates a `tf.Session()` by default it alocates almost all the GPU memory on your device. From the creenshot it seems that the session is instantiated, but no operation is actually being executed

Comment: Ok, but it is working. But CPU usage is relatively high... Is it possible that TF is allocating GPU memory, but is using CPU for calculations?

Comment: Possible, yes. Try removing the `with tf.device()` and leaving TF decide where to put each operation. Also, raise the log level to `info` and inspect the messages (you might find out that some operations cannot be put on the GPU so everything ends up on the CPU instead)

Comment: Removing `with tf.device()` helps nothing at all, GPU usage stays 0-1%. Is it possible to force tf to operate on gpu? Becuase learning on CPU with this model is so, so slow.